# How Would I Iterate Over 2 Lists In Python3 But If List 1 Is Exhausted Iterate Through It Again

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

So lets say I have 2 lists.

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, both lists are different lengths. Now I was wondering how I would make it so it iterates over both lists, but if list A has been fully iterated through, then iterate through List A again while still waiting for list B to be completed.

**Example Output**

```
A1
B2
C3
A4
B5
```

Not sure if this makes sense, if you want me to explain further I would be happy to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.cycle`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import cycle

A = cycle(['A', 'B', 'C'])
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for k,v in zip(A,B):
    print(f"{k}{v}")
```

**Output:**

```
A1
B2
C3
A4
B5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
m, n = len(A), len(B)
for idx in range(max(m, n)):
    print(f'{A[idx % m]}{B[idx % n]}')
```

**Output:**

```
A1
B2
C3
A4
B5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
j=0
for i in B:
    if j<len(A):
        print(f'{A[j]}{i}')
        j+=1
    else:
        j=0
        print(f'{A[j]}{i}')
        j+=1
```